# (Windows 8.1) Get path of selected folder from custom context menu option

Tags: windows, batch-file, command, registry, contextmenu

First of all, I have almost no idea about batch language. I'm working on a batch file that writes to the registry in order to add a context menu option that removes "desktop.ini" from the folder from where the context menu option is called. So far, what I got is:

```
@echo off

@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\resetFolderSettings"         /t REG_SZ /v "" /d "Reset folder settings"   /f
rem @reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\resetFolderSettings\command" /t REG_SZ /v "" /d "del /A s h \"%cd%\desktop.ini\" && pause" /f
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\resetFolderSettings\command" /t REG_SZ /v "" /d "cmd.exe /c echo \"%~dp0\desktop.ini\" && pause" /f

pause
```

Which doesn't work because what gets written into the registry is the static folder path from where the installation .bat is called. I'm having quite some trouble finding a solution to this problem so I finally decided I had no choice but to ask for help here.

Comment: Maybe you must you environment variable such as %ALLUSERSPROFILE% [Recognized Environment Variables]  (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560744(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: "from the folder from where the context menu option is called"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `%V` to denote the folder from where the context menu option is called.

Hence, the parameters you should use in

```
reg add "HKCR\Folder\shell\resetFolderSettings\command" ...
```

could be *from a batch script* (see that `%V` should be escaped as `%%V`):

```
 ... /t REG_SZ /v "" /d "%comspec% /c echo \"%%V\desktop.ini\"&&pause" /F
```

or *directly from `cmd` window* - `%` sign is not escaped here:

```
 ... /t REG_SZ /v "" /d "%comspec% /c echo \"%V\desktop.ini\"&&pause" /F
```

---

**Edit**. To make `%comspec%` expandable as well (and with operational `del /A` command instead of `echo`):

```
 ... /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /ve /d ^%comspec^%" /c del /A \"%V\desktop.ini\"&pause" /F
```

used directly from `cmd` window. See escaped `%` as `^%` (however only those *out of double-quoted part* of command line) above.

Use another escaping scheme from a batch-script: escape all `%` as `%%` how seen in both `%%comspec%%` and `%%V` as follows:

```
 ... /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /ve /d "%%comspec%% /c del /A \"%%V\desktop.ini\"&pause" /F
```

Result:

```
==> reg query "HKCR\Folder\shell\resetFolderSettings\command" /ve

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\resetFolderSettings\command
    (Default)    REG_EXPAND_SZ    %comspec% /c del /A "%V\desktop.ini"&pause
```

Comment: You can use `/ve` instead of `/v ""`

Comment: The output I get from that is always **"V\desktop.ini"**. I tried both "V" and "v" but none worked.
The command I tried was:

`@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\resetFolderSettings\command" /t REG_SZ /v "" /d "%comspec% /c echo \"%V\desktop.ini\" && pause" /f`

Comment: Fixed by adding a second `%` sign (`%%v`). Thanks.

Comment: @JesúsCruz Sorry, I have forgotten you are running it from a batch script; tried from command line only...